# Parallelizing reading a large text file into SQLite DB

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have a bit of code that I'm using to load a large text file (2 to 7GB) into a SQLite database, I wondered if there was a good way to parallelize this since I'm already chunking the text file to read it in?

```
def populate_sql(file):

  j = 1
  chunksize = 100000
  db_path = f"sqlite:///{file.split('.')[0]}.db"
  urls_database = create_engine(db_path)

  for df in tqdm(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, 
                        sep='\t', header=None, error_bad_lines = False), total = 100):
    df.columns = ['Date', 'LinkID', 'LinkURL', 'LinkText']  
    df.index += j
    df.to_sql("urls_table", urls_database, if_exists='append')
    j = df.index[-1] + 1
```

I have used multiprocessing before, but I can't immediately come up with a solution that doesn't step over itself when writing to a single DB. I also considered writing to multiple databases and then merging them later, but I wasn't sure how efficient that would be when I have to process 30+ files eventually?

Comment: Sqlite can't handle parallel write accesses to the same database. It would just need some profiling to find out if your idea about multiple DBs is useful.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks! I ended up trying the multiple-DB approach, but in the end, the added overhead and complexity of writing 100+ DBs and combining them was not worth the speedup in my particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The limiting factor will likely be the disk operations. Since the sqlite writes will tend to lock the file, I think that you are right that the code will step on itself. Instead, you could use threads to create a pipeline. While one thread waits on disk reads the other is processing writes, and visa-versa.

```
import threading
import queue

def sql_writer(in_q, db_path):
    urls_database = create_engine(db_path)
    j = 1
    while True:
        df = in_q.get()
        if df is None:
            in_q.task_done()
            return
        df.columns = ['Date', 'LinkID', 'LinkURL', 'LinkText']  
        df.index += j
        df.to_sql("urls_table", urls_database, if_exists='append')
        j = df.index[-1] + 1
        in_q.task_done()

def populate_sql(file):
    chunksize = 100000
    db_path = f"sqlite:///{file.split('.')[0]}.db"
    work_q = queue.Queue(2) # kinda arbitrary but don't want too many in flight
                            # df's to keep memory usage down
    work_thread = threading.Thread(target=sql_write, args=(work_q, db_path))
    work_thread.start()
    for df in tqdm(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, 
                        sep='\t', header=None, error_bad_lines = False), total = 100):
        work_q.put(df)
    work_q.put(None)
    work_q.join()
    work_thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @tdelaney! Unfortunately in my trials, using threads did not speed up execution. In fact, in scenarios with very large files, it was around 20% slower than the method in my original post, which is a bit confounding.